# Parse Config Image into a UIImageView

Tags: ios, parse-platform, backend

I have added an image in my apps 'Config' on Parse.com but I am unsure how to download the image from the 'Config' and show it in a `UIImageView` in my app once downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why I love Parse.com, they make it so easy for devs.

**STEP 1** Set up your parameter in your config admin view of Parse.com. For images you have to make sure it's set as a PFFile, and name it according to your needs.

[image: pic1]

**STEP 2** Implement the `getConfigInBackground:` method anywhere you need to call the Config parameters (not limited to images)

```
[PFConfig getConfigInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFConfig *config, NSError *error) {
    //In my case I have a BOOL statement, that if it is set to false, it won't show the config image I uploaded, it will show a placeholder image stored in the bundle
    if ([config[@"bannerisTrue"] boolValue]) {
        //The bannerisTrue boolValue is true so that means I want to retrieve the image from Config to display in the app
        PFFile *banner1 = config[@"banner1"]; //You reference the image as a PFFile first before retrieving the data, and you're telling the query to specify the config column 'banner1'. Kind of like `selectKeys:`
        [banner1 getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            UIImageView *bannerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:/*init how ever you want or place in whatever UIImageView you have a IBOutlet for */]; 
            bannerView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data]; //Your image is now in the UIImageView that you have set.
            }];
    } else {
        UIImageView *bannerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:/*same frame as above*/];
        bannerView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholderimage.jpg"]; //Since the boolValue is false we want to have a placeholder image so that way the app is more fluid. This is also good to have in case internet issues arise. This image is the one stored on device
    }
}];
```

Comment: Couldn't be anymore perfect and simpler. Thank you so much! Exactly thats why I use Parse so simple!